# outgoing ssh connections from unknown source - malware?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, security, malware

I "manage" a server running fedora 21. Some applications/programs were already installed when i started managing this server. It runs email server, git and a bunch other small things. It's also the router of this network.
Some time ago i get a report attacks have been made (ssh) originated from this server.
I've created a firewall rule to block and log ssh outgoing connections, and noticed that randomly there ssh connections to random ip's:
**IN= OUT=eno1 SRC=our.public.ip DST=45.61.142.74 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=22 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0**

It is originated from server (disabled lan network).

Some time ago, server as been compromised (stolen user password, tried to use "dead cow" exploit) and on other time, using testmail user (default from dovecot :( ), attempt to install mining malware (firefoxcatche).

I've tried everything i could remember and searched, but still not able to find out were/how connection is started.

Fresh install is not an option right now.

Thank you.

Comment: If there is a rootkit it is by design difficult to detect. When a server is known to have been compromised it should be mercilessly wiped out and reinstalled. Fun fact, the outgoing address you report is listed as a nuisance on the abuseipdb site. Control center for bots that run on your machine?

Comment: Yes, the optimal solution would be reinstall. But it is not possible at the moment, physically away from server at this time, and too many things to install/configure in optimal time...
I've run rkhunter and chkrootkit buto nothing suspicious found.
The destination IP's change also, but it seems that are just a few.
I remove ssh binary from is location, but the attempts go on in the same way.